# How to use Optuna to determine optimum of a parameter set without an objective function

Tags: python, optuna

I want to use [Optuna](https://optuna.org) to determine an optimum of a following data set:

[image: img]

All these parameters are used to find the optimal value in column optimum. The clou now is that these optimum values are not known until a device uses the parameters to run at these settings and bring up this specific optimum value at these parameters.
My problem is that I don't know how to realize this with Optuna. I had a look the tutorials but couldn't figure out which matches my task?

On https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/20_recipes/009_ask_and_tell.html#apply-optuna-to-an-existing-optimization-problem-with-minimum-modifications I've seen `You can apply Optuna’s hyperparameter optimization to your original code without an objective function.`

But I can't figure out how to adapt it to my task.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your data can be approached by multiple regression. You can use for example the [xboost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library to find the parameter coefficients to approximate your optimum values. Now the xgboost output can be optimized by optimizing its parameters too. You can then use optuna to optimize the parameters of xgboost.

Comment: Thank you! Might be a dumb question but for what exactly do I need (another xboost) library? Because I lack an objective function?

Comment: Yes you can use xgboost lib to create a model. You will train this model with the given data you have. Then when done use this model to predict the optimum value given the parameters. Lets say temp=21, filament=12000, etc, optimum=4. This is your true data. Now we will let the model predict the same parameters and outputed 8, the error then is 8-4 or 4, or squared_error is 4*4, basically that will become your objective function, to minimize the error. Notice there are more points to satisfy. We will tell optuna to minimize that, I will create an example if you need one.

Comment: Ok, understood, thank you! And simply using something like " optimum = filament + Injection_D + Injection_L + Contraction_D ..." directly in python is not sufficient? I'm just a bit concerned about the necessary hardware as the algorithm has to run on a micro controller later.

Comment: Btw, I don't think I'm able to train the model as each device is very unique and doesn't know any information about the other devices. Hence, how could/should I train?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the values in optimum column are from different devices?

Comment: no, it's the same device but the process itself is for multiple devices

Comment: Do you know xgboost?

Comment: We will train the model based on the data given. Once the model is created we can use it to predict the optimum column value given the parameters. It is not necessary to run the xgboost/optuna/model creation in micro controller, we use the desktop to create a model. What is useful is that if you have a parameter values to try we can already estimate its optimum value using the model.

Comment: Thanks, but I would need to train this for each device, right?

Comment: I assume each device have different optimal values depending of course on the parameters. Let's say device #1, get the data for this device and train a model say model #1 where the data is from device #1. The resulting model is only applicable for device #1. So for a given parameters intended for device #1, we will use model #1 to predict optimum value. This is one way of minimizing the noise from different devices. By identifying the noise we will be able to minimize the prediction error.

Comment: mh, this is an interesting approach I could use for another objective. But here, I need to select the most promising parameters for each device on its own. Hence, I thought the approach should be something like this "Select a certain parameter setting, apply it to the device, run the device, check the outcome (Optimum) and repeat this for three, four times or so to find the global optimum." This needs to be done for each device, independent from the others as the devices are very different to each other.

Comment: Even if the optimal values of the given parameters are not promising you need to include it in the dataset so that the model can learn from it.

Comment: The most crucial part is investigating the X and y values as I need to observe them with huge effort before training xgb on it. Hence, I would like to have Optuna to select the most promising X-values so the devices can evaluate corresponding y. How do I do that?

Comment: The thing that helps us first is the device why because the device would tell us the truth. Optuna, xgboost, lightgbm etc. can not help us without the data first.

Comment: But I need something that selects the data first. The data is there but I can't generate random data as it costs time and computational power to determine the data.

Comment: Could you tell us your situation?

Comment: I'm operating x-ray tubes for medical purposes and these tubes are very individual. Each is described by above parameters and Optimum reflects the deposited energy / dose to gain the best image as possible. As it's not possible to scan all parameters before each radiation (would take hours..) we have to find the best parameters as soon as possible, like within 3-5 iterations.

Comment: I don't know how this device is operated what I know after some reading is that you have some factors to get a good image, voltage, current, exposure time and others. What I mean with data are the histories of the device usage. If the data you posted are the histories of the device then we can use it to create a model. Once the model is created it is ready for use. For example we have a new subject, we prepare the input parameters for the device. We have filament, etc. We run our model in the desktop, input the parameters and get the optimum value within seconds. Now use that prediction value.

Comment: Got it, but the issue is that these tubes are changing physically over time. This means, their parameters are also changing why we have to re-calibrate them once in a month and it is always quite trial-and-error to find the best parameters. That's why I'm looking for a better method, means, one that suggests the most promising parameters to test.

Comment: That means the data you get is very noisy. But you can still continue and just measure the error. If the error is really big, then perhaps there is a missing parameter or feature that you have not considered in the data. Test it with same parameter and compare the optimum value, what is the difference?

Comment: One could say noisy, yeah. It is actually just changing or degrading, due to the applied high voltage and radiation. The optimum moves towards directions which are absolutely not understood at our side. Even the manufacturer does not know. Or in other words: The optimum changes in different ways for each tube. We have some guesses for the physical reasons but neither can we control them nor consider. If we would or could we would exceed the manufacturer's knowledge by far.

Comment: That is interesting indeed, One way to understand it is to keep a record. Perhaps these devices have logs.

Comment: if we were an academic instiution, yes. But the main task is to get them up and runnning as fast as possible so we lack the ressources. I mean, we are 2-3 people whereas the manufacturer has ~150 people and a history of 60 years producing these devices.